# android bind view repeating numerical display

Tags: android, android-cursor

The problem with the my list view is when you scroll up after you have reached the bottom the numbers keep incrementing. I wanted the numbers to be fixed. After the end of list view is reached and the user scrolls up. I am trying to filter the number of rows. I would post an image but I dont have the amount of points needed.

```
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
    // do your magic inhere :) the cursor will be at the correct row position
    System.out.println("please select a cursor");



    if(name_text != null) {
        String mFinal = answer.replaceAll("<ENTER>", "\n").replaceAll("<ENTER>", "").replaceAll("<COMMA>", ",");
        name_text.setText(String.valueOf(mFinal)); 
        correctanswer.setText(answer);
        questno.setText(String.valueOf(counter)); 
        counter++;
    }

    if(answer.equals(userreal))
    {
        System.out.println("are the two values equal");
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
        String mFinal = name.replaceAll("<ENTER>", "\n").replaceAll("<ENTER>", "").replaceAll("<COMMA>", ",");
        name_text.setText(String.valueOf(mFinal));
        myanswertext.setText(userreal);  
    }
    else
    {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.redcross);    
        String mFinal = name.replaceAll("<ENTER>", "\n").replaceAll("<ENTER>", "").replaceAll("<COMMA>", ",");
        name_text.setText(String.valueOf(mFinal));
        myanswertext.setText(userreal);
        System.out.println("are the values not equal"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see where you set any numbers... Am I missing something? Do you set numbers in getView()?

Comment: I updated my code. There is a counter and that sets the numbers

Comment: You _really_ should format your code before pasting it here, especially since most IDEs do it automatically. (In Eclipse, press Ctrl+A then Ctrl+I).

Comment: sorry will change the formating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the Cursor's position / index:

```
questno.setText(c.getPosition() + "");
```

Comment: I updated my answer, this should work more reliably than the first answer.

Comment: I understand why i was getting that error by just having the counter. It kept on incrementing even after I got to the end of the listview